# Nginx and favicon.ico - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" FAILED

Tags: nginx

How to I get rid of all the below errors in nginx.  I do not have a favicon.ico

```
2012/03/11 17:13:25 [error] 959#0: *116 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 111.68.59.75, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1"
```

I would imagine some line in nginx conf?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
location = /favicon.ico {
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: One should mention that this is a nginx setting. ``Edit the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/owncloud.conf`` (or similar) and add this. Then restart ``nginx``

OC community seems to discuss this topic as well.

Comment: I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to run a Ruby on Rails application.  I don't see any `/etc` folder, but i still get regular `/favicon.ico` not found errors.  Where can i set a similar configuration for Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @JeremyMoritz I am not familiar with AWS EB setup, but maybe this is what you are searching for? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709841/how-to-change-nginx-config-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-docker-instance

Comment: thanks, that was working perfectly. Is it a bad practice, or would there be a better place to "ignore" the favicon?

Comment: @Pfinnn please post your answer if you know a better way.

Answer (score 35):

The best solution for me is:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
  return 204;
  access_log     off;
  log_not_found  off;
}
```

Comment: Please mention the file name where we have to add this configuration.

Comment: @VishalShetty Inside your site server section at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

/etc/nginx/sites-available/fileName

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    
    location = /favicon.ico {
        return 204;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```