# AWS elastic load balancer timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

We've been testing Elastic Beanstalk against a misbehaving web app (that we, alas, have no control over).  Sometimes it takes longer than 60 seconds before sending the first bytes of a response, but at the 60 second mark the app sends a 504: Gateway Timeout message from nginx.

We need to set that 60 seconds to something higher.  We tried adding these settings to a file that we send to "aws eb create-environment..."

```
{ "Namespace": "aws:elb:policies:myPolicy",
"OptionName": "ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout", "Value": "300" }
```

But they don't seem to affect the 60 second timeout.  What are we doing wrong?

Comment: You're getting a message from nginx, not ELB so chaning ELB settings won't help.

Comment: that means I have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709841/how-to-change-nginx-config-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-docker-instance

Correct?

Comment: IDK to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported error could be from your [ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504), but more often than not it's from Nginx.  In the former case, you can raise the `IdleTimeout` to a higher limit using `AWS CLI`:

```
# Modify ELB idle-timeout
aws elb modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name <myloadbalancer> --load-balancer-attributes "{\"ConnectionSettings\":{\"IdleTimeout\":180}}"
```

In the latter case, consider raising the `keepalive_timeout` limit in `nginx.conf` within the `http` block similar to the following, then restart it (`sudo service nginx restart`):

```
http {
  // ...
  keepalive_timeout 180s;
}
```

Comment: fantastic.  Do you know handy how to specify the ngnix timeout via eb extensions?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I did all the configurative tuning of Nginx and ELB without using `ebextensions`.  Maybe examples in this [link](https://medium.com/trisfera/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c) will be of interest to you.